# Continuity of $h(x)=f(x) \cdot g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, function-and-relation-composition

$h(x)=f(x) \cdot g(x)$

I want to check whether this function is continuous in its domain $\mathbb{R}$ or not.

definition by cases:

1. $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both continuous $\Rightarrow f(x) \cdot g(x)$ is continuous (Composition of continuous functions)
2. Let w.l.o.g  g at $x_0$ be not continuous, this means $g(x) \neq g(x_0). \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0}((f \cdot g) (x)) = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) \cdot \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} g(x) = f(x_0) \cdot \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} g(x) \neq f(x_0) \cdot g(x_0)$

$\Rightarrow f(x) \cdot g(x)$ is at the same points discontinuous like the function $g$

This is what i've got so far... Is this correct? Is it necessary to check what happens, if $f, g$ are both discontinuous?

Comment: This is not quite correct. It is possible for $h$ to be continuous at a point where $g$ is not continuous. Looking through your work, do you see where/why this might happen?

Comment: If $f(x) = -g(x)$?

Comment: E.g. if $f(x_0)=0$. But $g$ not being continuous at $x_0$ may happen in *many situations* (e.g. has different left and right limit there, or perhaps one/both of these is $\pm\infty$, or just the limits don't exist at all...)

Comment: Um, is that $\cdot$ a composition or multiplication? Seem like you are implying that it's composition at one place and multiplication at another.

Comment: $\cdot$ is always multiplication

Answer (score 1):

The first statement in fully correct, yet for the second one you can find a really easy counterexample by taking $f(x)=0$.

Comment: So do i only have to except, that $f(x) \neq 0$ or is my whole argumentation wrong?

Comment: The main problem with you argumentation is that if the functions f and g are non continuous you can't simply take the limit of their multiplication as the multiplication of their limits

Comment: Should i just say it depends?

Comment: You simply have to go through a simple case division:
1) left and right limit of $g(x)$ in $x_0$ exist and are different, then you simply multiply them with a continuous function in $x_0$ which is equal to 0 and you can remove the incontinuity in $f*g$
2) the function grows to $+-oo$ in $x_0$. Then you have to dominate the function with a faster dropping one (which is always possible to find) such that the left and right limits of $f*g$ converge in $x_0$ to some value.